# Use Agda's input method in other emacs mode?

Tags: emacs, unicode, customization, tex, agda

How do I use Agda's input method to enter unicode characters in non-Agda mode? I don't see its name showing up when I try `set-input-method`. The reason I want to use Agda's input method instead of `TeX` is because there are characters I want that can't enter in `TeX`.

Or, maybe an alternate question would be "How do I add more shortcuts to enter unicode characters in the existing `TeX` input method?"

Thank you very much

Comment: really nice with `haskell-mode` + `Prelude.Unicode` + `-XUnicodeSyntax`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the following commands in your .emacs file:

```
;; Using the input method of Agda in LaTeX files.
(require 'agda-input)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set-input-method "Agda")))
```

Comment: Turns out `(require 'agda-input)` was all I needed in my case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually in my case, my LaTeX files use the input method of Agda because I added the hook to the Text mode instead of the LaTeX mode.

Comment: `(require 'agda-input)` should be put *after* `(load-file (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
      (shell-command-to-string "agda-mode locate")))`